# Deploying VB.Net Web Application to Azure

Tags: vb.net, azure, web-applications

I am attempting to deploy a 2019 VB.Net Application to Azure.

I have successfully migrated the SQL-express database to the cloud.

My azure account is also connected to my visual studio application.

When I right click on my application on the solution explorer and press deploy.

The following appears.

[Image that appears after I click deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0nnr.png)

On the youtube tutorials I have seen when they right click on the project in solution explorer it then brings them to a page enabling them to deploy to azure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019 ?

Comment: Would you have any interest in putting your code in source control (eg git  on bitbucket or github) and then having azure auto deploy from source control when updates are pushed to the repo?